# How can I get Running Deduction Amount and Running Balance on MS Access Query?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've been working on this query for a while now (MS ACCESS 2016)...

I have two related tables: Loan Table and Deduction Table

**LOAN TABLE:**

```
loan_id   employee_id   loan_date   loan_amount  is_posted
-------   -----------   ----------  -----------  ---------
   1           1        06/01/2019   15,000.00     True
   2           4        06/01/2019    2,000.00     True
```

**DEDUCTION TABLE:**

```
deduction_id  loan_id  deduction_date  deduction_amount  is_posted
------------  -------  --------------  ----------------  ---------
   D1_1          1       01/15/2020         500.00         True
   D1_2          1       01/30/2020         500.00         True
   D1_3          1       02/15/2020         300.00         False
   D1_4          1       02/28/2020         100.00         True
   D2_1          2       01/15/2020       1,000.00         False
   D2_2          2       01/30/2020         200.00         True
   D2_3          2       02/15/2020         500.00         True
```

From these tables, I'm trying to get RUNNING DEDUCTION and RUNNING BALANCE through a query to get this kind of result:
(I will populate this result into an Excel Userform ListBox using ADODB)

**RUNNING DEDUCTION/BALANCE QUERY: [THIS IS THE DESIRED RESULT]**

```
deduction_id  loan_id  deduction_date  deduction_amount  RunDeduct    RunBal
------------  -------  --------------  ----------------  ---------  ---------
    D1_4         1       02/28/2020         100.00       1,100.00   14,400.00
    D1_2         1       01/30/2020         500.00       1,000.00   14,500.00
    D1_1         1       01/15/2020         500.00         500.00   15,000.00
    D2_3         2       02/15/2020         500.00         700.00    1,300.00
    D2_2         2       01/30/2020         200.00         200.00    1,800.00
```

In this sample query:

- the only DEDUCTION records displayed are those table_deduction.is_posted=True
- also, the query should only include the deduction_amount with is_posted=True in the calculation of Running Deduction and Running Balance
- It is sorted by date from newest to oldest

---

Query calculation I'm trying to achieve:

- Running Balance = Loan Amount - Deduction Amount *then it will
  become... *
- Running Balance = Previous Balance - (recent posted) Deduction Amount
- Running Deduction = (1st) Deduction Amount *then it will become...*
- Running Deduction = Previous Deduction Amount + (recent posted)
  Deduction Amount

---

So far, I was able to get the running totals using this

```
SELECT
    TD.deduction_id,
    TD.loan_id,
    TD.deduction_date,
    TD.deduction_amount,
    (SELECT Sum(deduction_amount) FROM t_deduction WHERE TD.deduction_date >= deduction_date AND TD.loan_id = loan_id) AS RunnPaid,
    TL.loan_amount-RunnPaid AS RunnBalance
FROM
    t_loan AS TL
INNER JOIN
    t_deduction AS TD ON TL.loan_id = TD.loan_id
ORDER BY
    TD.loan_id, TD.deduction_date DESC;
```

But whenever I try to associate the 't_deduction.is_posted' field, it messes up the whole query. It still includes the 'not posted' records in the calculation.

```
SELECT
    TD.deduction_id,
    TD.loan_id,
    TL.loan_amount,
    TD.deduction_date,
    TD.deduction_amount,
    (SELECT Sum(deduction_amount) FROM t_deduction WHERE TD.deduction_date >= deduction_date AND TD.loan_id = loan_id AND TD.is_posted=True) AS RunnPaid,
    TL.loan_amount-RunnPaid AS RunnBalance
FROM
    t_loan AS TL
INNER JOIN
    t_deduction AS TD ON TL.loan_id = TD.loan_id
WHERE
    TD.is_posted = True
ORDER BY
    TD.loan_id, TD.deduction_date DESC;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should provide data as formatted text tables, not images. Also, provide the attempted SQL. What does "messes up" mean? This might be easier to accomplish in report using textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: @June7 Hi, For some reason, whenever I try to add 'formatted text tables' the whole formatting of the question gets messed up. However, I've added the 'working code' and 'messing code'. Actually, I will populate the 'desired result' into Excel Userform ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the nested SQL criteria to use t_deduction.is_posted instead of TD.is_posted - just remove `TD.`:

```
(SELECT Sum(deduction_amount) FROM t_deduction WHERE TD.deduction_date >= deduction_date 
 AND TD.loan_id = loan_id AND is_posted=True) AS RunnPaid,
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem arises from the identifier scope of "td.is_posted" within the correlated subquery. You may try the following code and let me know if it works:

```
SELECT
    TD.deduction_id, TD.loan_id, TL.loan_amount,
    TD.deduction_date, TD.deduction_amount,
    (SELECT Sum(deduction_amount) FROM t_deduction WHERE TD.deduction_date >= deduction_date AND TD.loan_id = loan_id AND is_posted) AS RunnPaid,
    TL.loan_amount-RunnPaid AS RunnBalance
FROM
    t_loan AS TL
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT deduction_id, loan_id, deduction_date, deduction_amount
    FROM t_deduction
    WHERE is_posted ) AS TD
ON TL.loan_id = TD.loan_id
ORDER BY
    TD.loan_id, TD.deduction_date DESC;
```

I am assuming that "is_posted" is a Bool (or Yes/No). Otherwise, replace "is_posted" by "is_posted = TRUE".

Comment: Whoa! This one works too! Thank you so much! <3